# Callback function of pthread_create not getting called?

Tags: c++, multithreading

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std;

class Base

{
    private:
    public:

        void threadCall1( void * value)
        {
            cout<<"inside threadCall1"<<endl;
            cout<<"Value is"<<(int *)value<<endl;

        }

    protected:

};

class Derived
{
    private:
    public:
        void threadCall2 ();
    protected:



};

void *passValue(void * q)
{

    cout<<"inside passValue"<<endl;
    Base *b = new Base();
    b->threadCall1(q);
    cout<<"after threadCall1"<<endl;
    Derived *d;
    cout<<(int *)q<<endl;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

 void Derived::threadCall2()
{
    cout<<"inside threadCall2"<<endl;

}
int main ()
{
    int k = 2;
    pthread_t t1;
    cout<<"inside main"<<endl;

    pthread_create(&t1,NULL,&passValue,(void *)k);
    cout<<"after pthread_create"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
inside main
after pthread_create
```

Everything seems fine but don't know why `passValue` is not getting called and I get the above output but other logs namely `inside passValue` is missing

Comment: May i know the reason for downvote :(

Comment: When your first thread returns out of main, the process exits. So your second thread probably hasn't enough time to do something.

Comment: @tkausl yeah you are right I added a `sleep(1)` and could see the exact output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `main` terminates early and kills the thread immediately after creation. Add this line before `return 0;` of the main:

```
pthread_join(t1, NULL);
```

This will make the main thread wait for (blocks) for the termination of `t1`.